# jQuery/CSS: Assigning classes to a table depends on their order

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this table:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

...
</tbody>
```

and it keeps going...
I want on doc ready to add class odd and even depends on their position. To end up something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="odd">
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    ...
    </tbody>
```

What is the way to achieve this? Do I have to count how many tables I have and add classes depends on their position? It doesn't sound safe/proper way to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a pure CSS solution, go with jQUery and use `:odd` / `:even` selectors. Otherwise Sirko's solution is better. (Note that nth-child method would not run on IE8 and below)

```
​$("table tr:odd").addClass("odd");
​$("table tr:even").addClass("even");
```

Comment: Why haven't I thought of it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `nth-child` pseudoselector [(MDN link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3anth-child).

In case you just want to assign some styles use:

```
tr:nth-child(2n+1) { // odd rows }
tr:nth-child(2n) { // even rows }
```

**EDIT :**

As suggested by David Thomas this would improve readability:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) { // odd rows }
tr:nth-child(even) { // even rows }
```

Comment: I'd suggest `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` for a slight ease-of-use improvement.